# Testing Android for Out of Memory scenarios

Tags: android, unit-testing

Is there a good way of testing androids for out of memory scenarios? I'd like to be able to specifically choose an application running on the emulator and force the emulator to recycle its activity stack.  I know there's a way to verify different parts of your activities via Instrumentation Test Cases (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/testing/activity_testing.html).

Wondering if there's anything else that can force the application to do it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

What about using the MonkeyRunner tool?  You can program it to run through however many scenarios needed e.g. screen rotations, finishing activities, etc. etc.  It could server the purpose of your question.

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/monkeyrunner_concepts.html

There's also the monkey application exerciser:

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/monkey.html

Comment: Seems like the best approach for this.  Would be cool to have an app on maybe a rooted phone which could force applications to clean up their activity stack.

Comment: down - usuless / broken links