# Simulate Out of Memory in android

Tags: android, out-of-memory

This is the case when I want to simulate an Out of memory crash in my application. I have a lot of crashes from Crashlytics which indicate that end users are running into OOM crashes and I have not been able to reproduce them with my device (Samsung S4). I just have crashes and no other traces from crashlytics.

I was wondering if someone has a way to reproduce them for their testing (without any code change preferred).

I saw this : [Testing Android for Out of Memory scenarios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885161/testing-android-for-out-of-memory-scenarios) , but haven't got a chance to run it yet.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you going to debug the real issue if you artificially tell the app it's out of memory? There are definitely tools for analyzing your heap, but they don't provide much value in artificial conditions since everything will look normal...

Comment: No, I am not going to artificially do it . This is why I said - without any code change. What I wanted to ask is that if like opening a lot of apps and switching between them or any other way to make that happen (like any settings or any other app that can be used)

Answer (score 4):

There are a variety of ways to cause OOM.

1. Use a very large image (incidentally, this use-case is a source of many real OOM issues in apps).  I replaced the image for 1 element in my Recycler, so when I scroll to it, it will load the large image (then I can drive the test that way).
2. Create a loop, that allocates objects to memory.  You can just "new" up a bunch of objects in a loop, and run it that way.  If you allocate enough Strings, or int objects into a single array, this will run OOM eventually (this is also a good way to gradually build to an OOM condition).  Strings will cause OOM faster then ints (but add enough objects to an array, and eventually it will become too large).

Answer (score 2):

I was able to simulate the OOM error by replacing a list of images in the app very large images. 5mb instead of usual 250k. Wikimedia has lot large images you can use. https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Snake_River_(5mb).jpg

Answer (score 0):

I hope I'm understanding the question correctly: There's a very easy way if you don't want to change a lot of settings. Go into dev options and make it "no background processeses". Now you can exit out of the app, launch a new one and go back into your original and it'll be wiped out from out of memory

Comment: No the OP is asking how to simulate a scenario where either the device has run out of memory (unlikely) or the app has consumed it's own heap by leaking memory causing further memory allocations to fail and the app to crash (more likely).